# Insert space with spacebar after HTML in contenteditable DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard-events

Context: I have a `contenteditable div` that a user can type or insert emojis into. I've noticed that the emojis (which are just `img` elements) render appropriately to the user, but on the actual reply/comment, they only come through correctly IF I MANUALLY HIT THE SPACEBAR or insert another character immediately after the `img` is added.

Problem: Using jQuery, I have been unable to mimic the spacebar's functionality when I detect that the user has added an `img`.

I have tried a few different methods, scouring SO and Google, and have had no luck.

The HTML:

```
<div class="text">
    <div class="emojionearea emojiable-text-input emojionearea-inline">
        <div class="emojionearea-editor" contenteditable="true" 
        placeholder="Type answer here" tabindex="0" dir="ltr" 
        spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off">     
            TEXT AND IMAGES GO HERE
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's some sample code that I've written to try to imitate an actual PRESS of the spacebar, with the intent of a space being inserted into the `div` html:

```
var text_input_for_emojis = $('div.text > div > div.emojionearea-editor')
```

These are fired off after I detect the `img` tag being added. That part of my functionality is working fine, so I'm only going to ask you guys to focus on the actual functionality of mimicking the spacebar.

```
text_input_for_emojis.focus().trigger(jQuery.Event('keydown', { keycode: 32 }));
```

No luck. Tried this:

```
text_input_for_emojis.focus().trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 32 }));
```

Again, no luck. Tried this, which doesn't deal with the spacebar, and doesn't solve the problem either:

```
text_input_for_emojis.after(' ')
```

It doesn't seem to add a `' '` to the `html` of the `div` (`text_input_for_emojis`).

Any thoughts on what could be going on here?

[image]

Notice in my demo: The first time through, the emoji doesn't copy down correctly WITHOUT ME HITTING THE SPACE BAR. The 2nd time, it works, AFTER HITTING THE SPACEBAR.

Comment: We need to see your html to make the magic slush in our brains to work. Just kidding. It would be helpful if we could see you html though. @tman091

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade - updated with more code!

Comment: Can you also add the code where you send it to the backend?  I'm presuming this is done using ajax?  If so, you can append the space character prior to the ajax call.

Comment: Updated @user9263373 @TheOneWhoMade - I guess I was misleading. This is all front end. We're dealing with copying the html from the `contenteditable` div into another div.

Comment: Hey, you seem pretty good at html, could you look at my question at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/153672/how-to-access-files-in-chrome/153690#153690 @tman091

Answer (score 0):

Change `$(text_input_for_emojis)` to `text_input_for_emojis` like this.

```
var text_input_for_emojis = $('div.text > div > div.emojionearea-editor')

text_input_for_emojis.focus().trigger(jQuery.Event('keydown', { keycode: 32 }));
```

Comment: This does not appear to work. There is no space added on to the HTML content of the div. My thought with this solution is that it would mimic the press of the space bar, which should add a space to the div. It doesn't appear to do that. @user9263373

Comment: @tman091 I get what you were trying to accomplish.  I thought since you were assigning your jquery selector to a variable, you didn't need to use the `$(...)` to reference it.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right on that. No need to use `$(...)`. :)